# Сравнение полей одной таблицы Yii

Tags: yii

Необходимо сравнить поля одной таблицы на равенство, как сделать?

> $criteria->compare
> ('floor','floor_total');

такая штука не работает

Comment: Что должно произойти в результате данного сравнения? От этого зависит конкретный ответ.

Comment: Вообще выводиться выводиться элементы у которых floor = total_floor. Я таким образом хочу найти квартиры на последнем этаже

Answer (score 1):

> $criteria->addCondition('floor = floor_total');

заработало так